# How to iterate recursively linkedhashmap data type in python

Tags: python, jython

I have hierarchical data coming from source. when I do `type(data)` in python to know the data type i get `linkedhashmap`. I have to write a recursive function in Python to find an element. My problem is I don't know how to check if `datatype` is an instance of `linkedhashmap`. For example to check if data is a dictionary i can do `isinstance(data, dict)` in python which will tell if the incoming data is `dict` or not, but i don't know the keyword for `linkedhashmap`. Also, when I am doing something like this

```
for item in linkedhashmapdata:
    print type(linkedhashmapdata[item])
```

This also result to `linkedhashmap`. I have to write a recursive function something like this:

```
def find(key, dictionary):
    for k, v in dictionary.iteritems():
        if k == key:
            yield v
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            for result in find(key, v):
                yield result
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            for d in v:
                for result in find(key, d):
                    yield result
```

Comment: Which interpreter are you using? It kind of sounds like Jython.

Comment: Yes, you are right it is jython